# Locate many to many extra relationship attribute with Spring data

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I have some problem with many to many query. This is part of my database
[image: many to many]

and this is the code of my relationship class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "notification_has_user", catalog = "ats")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.user", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_username")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.notification", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_notification")) })
public class NotificationHasUser implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private NotificationHasUserKeys pk = new NotificationHasUserKeys();
    private boolean isRead;

    @EmbeddedId
    public NotificationHasUserKeys getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    /**
     * @param pk the pk to set
     */
    public void setPk(NotificationHasUserKeys pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Transient
    public User getUser() {
        return getPk().getUser();
    }

    public void setStock(User user) {
        getPk().setUser(user);
    }

    @Transient
    public Notification getNotification() {
        return getPk().getNotification();
    }

    public void setCategory(Notification notification) {
        getPk().setNotification(notification);
    }

    @Column(name = "isRead", nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
    public boolean isRead() {
        return isRead;
    }

    /**
     * @param isRead the isRead to set
     */
    public void setRead(boolean isRead) {
        this.isRead = isRead;
    }
..equal and hash code
}
```

Now I need to retrieve the list of all unread messages, therefore all the notifications with field isRead = 0.
I have tried with thess Spring query

```
List<Notification> findByPkUserAndIsReadFalse(Useruser);
```

and also with this:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM NotificationHasUser c WHERE c.pk.user = ?1 AND c.isRead=false")
```

but the field isRead gives me problem and this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [isRead] on this ManagedType [com.domain.NotificationHasUser]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.AbstractManagedType.checkNotNull(AbstractManagedType.java:144) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.AbstractManagedType.getAttribute(AbstractManagedType.java:130) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(QueryUtils.java:475) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator$PredicateBuilder.build(JpaQueryCreator.java:199) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.toPredicate(JpaQueryCreator.java:146) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.and(JpaQueryCreator.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.and(JpaQueryCreator.java:44) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:109) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:73) ~[spring-data-commons-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:110) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$CountQueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:230) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:64) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:94) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Could you explain me where is the mistake?

Comment: I made a mistake the name of isRead method, it must be getIsRead and setIsRead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the `boolean` field to `read` and use `isRead` and `setRead` as its getter and setter, this way it's more aligned with Java Beans specification.

Comment: yes I commented my post with the error but I'm waiting to test the method and know if it works before accept